# Define groups of columns and sum all i-th columns of each groups with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two groups of columns, each with 36 columns, and I want to sum all i-th column of group 1 with i-th column of group2, getting 36 columns. The number of columns in each group is not fix in my code, although each group has the same number of them.

Exemple. What I have:

```
teste <- tibble(a1=c(1,2,3),a2=c(7,8,9),b1=c(4,5,6),b2=c(10,20,30))
     a1    a2    b1    b2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     7     4    10
2     2     8     5    20
3     3     9     6    30
```

What I want:

```
resultado <- teste %>%
  summarise(
    a_b1 = a1+b1,
    a_b2 = a2+b2
  )
   a_b1  a_b2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     5    17
2     7    28
3     9    39
```

It would be nice to perform this operation with dplyr.

I would thank any help.

Answer (score 2):

You will struggle to find a dplyr solution as simple and elegant as the base R one:

```r
teste[1:2] + teste[3:4]
#>   a1 a2
#> 1  5 17
#> 2  7 28
#> 3  9 39
```

Though I guess in dplyr you get the same result with:

```r
teste %>% select(starts_with("a")) + teste %>% select(starts_with("b"))
```

Comment: How can I make a group of columns with the result?

Answer (score 2):

```
 teste %>%
   summarise(across(starts_with("a")) + across(starts_with("b")))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
     a1    a2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     5    17
2     7    28
3     9    39
```

Comment: But I have NAs. I tried colSums(across(starts_with("a")),across(starts_with("b")),na.rm=T) and didn't work...

Comment: @Giornni why do you want `colSums`? `across` is a `tidyverse` function` and only works with the five verb functions in `dplyr`

Comment: Because I have NAs. How can I sum these columns ignoring NAs? Using sum(across(starts_with("a")),across(starts_with("b")),na.rm=T) results in a tibble with 1 column

Comment: @Giornni you need `summarise` not `sum`. Look at the answer given

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to explain that the problem I'm having is in my code, not the reproducible exemple. Another exemple:  tibble(a1=c(1,2,3),a2=c(7,8,9),b1=c(4,5,NA),b2=c(10,NA,30))

Comment: @Giornni what answer do you want for that?

Comment: tibble(a_b1=c(5,7,3),a_b2=c(17,8,39))

Comment: @Giornni do `df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~replace_na(.x, 0))) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("a")) + across(starts_with("b")))`

Comment: It's a pleasure meeting you again dear Onyambu.

Answer (score 2):

This might also help in base R:

```
as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, lapply(split.default(teste, sub("\\D(\\d+)", "\\1", names(teste))), rowSums, na.rm = TRUE))) 

  1  2
1 5 17
2 7 28
3 9 39
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `dplyr` solution. We can use `rowwise` and `c_across` together to sum the values per row. Notice that we can add `na.rm = TRUE` to the `sum` function in this case.

```
library(dplyr)

teste2 <- teste %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  transmute(a_b1 = sum(c_across(ends_with("1")), na.rm = TRUE),
            a_b2 = sum(c_across(ends_with("2")), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup()
  
teste2
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#    a_b1  a_b2
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     5    17
# 2     7    28
# 3     9    39
```